# fill rest of the space using linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a [FoodCardFragment](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_food_card.xml) that has a `CardView` at the bottom. I want the `CardView` to have a height of at least 120dp and fill the rest of the space (so I set its `layout_weight` to 1).

The `FoodCardFragment` is put in the [RandomFragment](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_random.xml) (the first tab of [MainAcitivity](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)), and also has its `layout_weight` set to 1 as I want it to fill the rest of the space.

However, as you can tell from the image I posted below, the yellow `CardView` I mentioned above doesn't fill the rest of the space. How can I achieve my goal?

[image]

In case the links won't work:

Code for FoodCardFragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/food_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/food_image"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_image_place_holder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/liked_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_undo_like" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/food_card" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/more_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tags_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="120dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_note_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/food_note_background"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_note_front"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/food_note_background"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for RandomFragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/whiteSmoke">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/random"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/filter_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/menu_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/food_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/food_card_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/check_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cross_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cross" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which is your yellow view in xml you have posted?

Comment: @PankajKumar It is the background of the 2 `TextView`s inside the `CardView` aforementioned.